# change position of compass needle animation so it doesn't point north

Tags: java, android

I have been experimenting with the compass.java sample code in the android sdk.

I was wondering how I would go about changing the code so that at certain compass positions the animated object moves to a certain place other than to magnetic north.

e.g. when the phone is pointing south it is pointing east or west

when the phone is pointing east or west it points north east or north west respectively

Code: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Compass.html

```
package com.example.android.apis.graphics;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Config;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class Compass extends GraphicsActivity {

private static final String TAG = "Compass";

private SensorManager mSensorManager;
private Sensor mSensor;
private SampleView mView;
private float[] mValues;

private final SensorEventListener mListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (Config.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG,
                "sensorChanged (" + event.values[0] + ", " + event.values[1] + ", " + event.values[2] + ")");
        mValues = event.values;
        if (mView != null) {
            mView.invalidate();
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    mView = new SampleView(this);
    setContentView(mView);
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    if (Config.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();

    mSensorManager.registerListener(mListener, mSensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    if (Config.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mListener);
    super.onStop();
}

private class SampleView extends View {
    private Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
    private Path    mPath = new Path();
    private boolean mAnimate;

    public SampleView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Construct a wedge-shaped path
        mPath.moveTo(0, -50);
        mPath.lineTo(-20, 60);
        mPath.lineTo(0, 50);
        mPath.lineTo(20, 60);
        mPath.close();
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint paint = mPaint;

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        int h = canvas.getHeight();
        int cx = w / 2;
        int cy = h / 2;

        canvas.translate(cx, cy);
        if (mValues != null) {
            canvas.rotate(-mValues[0]);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        mAnimate = true;
        if (Config.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onAttachedToWindow. mAnimate=" + mAnimate);
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        mAnimate = false;
        if (Config.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onDetachedFromWindow. mAnimate=" + mAnimate);
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The animation object will change depending on the direction the phone is pointed when lied down.
I was thinking that I would need to change the even.values[0] to manipulate the position?

Comment: if (mValues != null) {
   canvas.rotate(-mValues[0]);
}
the mValues[0] contains the current value of the compass in 360 degrees so to edit an object's popsition i will need to change this number.

I have also found that if you value the mValue[n] n number it changes the senor value it uses 0 = compass 1 = tilt forward and back 2 = tilt side to side